# Open custom address by CameraRoll().browseForImage();

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, flash-cs6

I need to open gallery file in custom address in my Android app.

For example my photo camera saves in address "DCIM/SHEKAR/"

I use Adobe Flash CS6 and Adobe AIR.

My code:

```
       camera_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseHandler);
function mouseHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
       var mediaFile:CameraRoll = new CameraRoll();
       var imagePromise:MediaPromise;
       CameraRoll(mediaFile).browseForImage();

}
```

But open default address.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently it's no way to change default gallery address. Method **browseForImage** always shows default gallery.

Comment: so how to open this directory ?

Comment: you can't do it, only default directory

Comment: tanx , i know , but can i open this directory "DCIM/SHEKAR/" , like open new windows in win . ?!

Comment: You can create your own popup window and navigate to necessary directory inside. Take a look to this example: http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2010/11/30/Simple-mobile-directory-browser-built-with-AIR